# Django ORM and Unicode data

Tags: python, django, orm, unicode, django-models

I'm using following model to store info about pages:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(blank = False, null = False)
```

New data saves correctly, I'm saving Unicode data there (lots of non-ASCII titles).
But when I'm performing query:

```
page = Page.objects.filter(id = 1)
```

page.title looks odd:

```
u'\u042e\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e'
```

What could I made wrong?
Thanks.

**Update**: Really, when I'm print page.title - it looks OK. 
But I need to dump it to JSON, so after such code:

```
dumps({'title': page.title})
```

All looks bad.

**Update 2**: Thanks to everyone, pointed me that this behavoir is correct. But unicode-escaped strins are so long. Can I translate them to utf-8 somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct behaviour: `dumps` encodes the json for you. It looks ugly now, but that's just for transmission. To see your unicode string again have to decode it (usually on the other end):

```
>>> from django.utils.simplejson import dumps, loads
>>> original = u'\u042e\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e'
>>> print original
Ющенко
>>> encoded = dumps(original)
>>> print encoded
"\u042e\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e"
>>> decoded = loads(encoded)
>>> print decoded
Ющенко
```

Generally you won't need to decode it in python, it'll get loaded as a unicode string in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing nothing wrong. Have you tried printing it (or outputting it in a web page)?

```
In [1]: l = u'\u042e\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e'

In [2]: print l
Ющенко
```

Comment: I don't need this string to be printed. That's my problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly fine. It's "Ющенко" unicode-escaped.

Comment: Is there any way to translate unicode-escaped string to normal?

Comment: You can use `s.encode('utf8')` to get a UTF8 representation of the string. Whether that is what you want depends on your client code.

Comment: I've tried all possible encodes-decodes combinations. 
I simply need to convert this representation to common unicode str.

Comment: That IS a common Unicode string. The slashes are just how Python unicode literals are written.

Answer (score 1):

Might just be your shell not being able to display unicode characters maybe?

What happens if you do `print page.title`?

Comment: Printed string is OK, but I need to dump it to json

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with what you have posted so far.

```
>>> print json.dumps(u'\u042e\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e')
"\u042e\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e"
```

Which is a correct JavaScript string literal. Assign that to a variable and you'll get `Ющенко` in a JavaScript string.

What is the actual problem? What “looks bad”?

Comment: Thanks! I thought that strings must be in UTF-8